# How to run sensu-client as a standalone application? (No dependency on rabbitmq)

Tags: windows, sensu

I want to be able to run `sensu-client` as a standalone app without any dependency on an external rabbitmq. I basically just want the `sensu-client` to use email handler if a check script detects a problem.

Currently I have installed a sensu-client on MS-windows as a Windows service.

```
{"timestamp":"2015-01-13T14:25:41.513142+1100","level":"warn","message":"loading config file","file":"C:/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json"}
{"timestamp":"2015-01-13T14:25:42.669581+1100","level":"error","message":"[amqp] Detected TCP connection failure"}
{"timestamp":"2015-01-13T14:25:42.669581+1100","level":"fatal","message":"transport connection error","error":"failed to connect to rabbitmq"}
{"timestamp":"2015-01-13T14:25:42.669581+1100","level":"warn","message":"stopping"}
{"timestamp":"2015-01-13T14:25:42.669581+1100","level":"info","message":"completing checks in progress","checks_in_progress":[]}
{"timestamp":"2015-01-13T14:25:43.185368+1100","level":"warn","message":"stopping reactor"
```

The service dies after these error messages.

Is the dependency on rabbitmq optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read over the last few days, **no**. The sensu-client is inherently tied to RabbitMQ and automatically tries to send results to the message queue.

You might want to look at something akin to [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) or [god](http://godrb.com/) which may well do what you wish without the RabbitMQ dependency.